# Webscraping from pop up using python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the course data from the website : 'https://schedule.msu.edu/'. After selecting the term, subject and clicking on 'Find Courses' button, a list of courses appears and by clicking on each course, for eg: (course AAAS 100 in the term: Fall 2019, subject: African American & African Studies), a popup window appears and I tried getting the data from the popup using selenium, it throws an exception saying "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:". Once the pop up opens up, its a different URL, but I am unable to figure out how to get the data from the popup. I would greatly appreciate any help on this matter.

Here is a sample code using selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://schedule.msu.edu/")


check_box=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_chkAllonePg']").click()
#clicking on the "terms"
term=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_ddlTerm']")
term.click()

#selecting a term
term_op=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_ddlTerm']/option[3]")
term_op.click()

#selecting the subject
elem_sub=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_ddlSubject']").click()                                    
subject=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_ddlSubject']/option[1]")
subject.click()

#Clicking on 'Find Courses' button
elem_search=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_btnSubmit']")
elem_search.click()

#Clicking on a course to get the popup
course=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_divHeader1_va']/h3[1]/a").click()

#Trying to Scrape from the popup
pop_up=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='RepeaterMain']/tbody/tr[1]/td/h3")
pop_up.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those elements are wrapped in a frame, so you should switch to that frame first.
This code should work:

```
#Clicking on a course to get the popup
course=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='MainContent_divHeader1_va']/h3[1]/a").click()

#Trying to Scrape from the popup
#pop_up=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='RepeaterMain']/tbody/tr[1]/td/h3")
time.sleep(5)
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='CourseFrame']"))
#print(driver.page_source)
time.sleep(5)
try:            
    pop_up=WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='RepeaterMain']/tbody/tr[1]/td/h3")))
    print(pop_up.text)
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

the output:

```
AAAS 390  Special Topics in Black/Africana Studies
```

Comment: Thanks Huynh, this works! Any idea on how to close the popup after extracting the data? I tried finding the xpath of the close button and included that after the print(pop_up.text) statement, but it throws NoSuchElementException (we are passing the exception here)

Comment: you should switch out the frame before click close button. something like this: driver.switch_to.default_content()

Comment: how did you get the xpath as "//*[@id='CourseFrame']" ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a frame inside the popup modal. You have to switch to that frame before you can access the elements inside the frame.

Try this :

```py
#Trying to Scrape from the popup
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("CourseFrame"))
pop_up=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='RepeaterMain']")
print(pop_up.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed, but it throws NoSuchFrameException, but I got the point of switching the frames.